# MongooseTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoose version = 5.8.11 mongo version = 3.4.7 node version = 10.15.3

it works fine for a couple days, then i get this error and sometimes it does connect and sometimes it does not, i am not using mongo :

> (node:8714) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseTimeoutError:
>   Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = () => { const mongoObj = mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/database', { useUnifiedTopology: true }); return mongoObj; };
```

Comment: But you are using mongo?

Comment: Should there be `'mongodb://localhost:27017/database` ?

Comment: yes, mongo is running in docker container "mongo" with mongodb version 3.4.7

Comment: Oh you need provide us with docker commands or docker-compose or whatever you use

Comment: there is a docker image runing, the url is not the problem, it has worked for a long time, it just started crashing after a few days

Comment: @AlejoCano did you figure out the problem? I'm faceing the same problem just with local server